# When User joins voice channel bot joins, when user leaves bot leaves

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am wondering how I would make my bot join the voice channel a specific user joins and then when the user leaves that channel the bot leaves or moves to the other channel the user has moved to.

I was trying to do this but really don't know how I would go about doing it.

Comment: Please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), what's the current result, what's the expected result, what errors are you getting, etc... We don't write code for others here

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using discord.py, you can easily use the `voice_state_update` event for handling this.

```py
@<Bot>.event
async def on_voice_state_update(oldState, newState):
     # if user joined a new channel
     if oldState.channel is None and newState.userID == [id]:
           # do stuff here
```

Comment: It doesn't work?